# the 'torah' tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah) tag is named overly generally. (The vast majority of questions on the main site have *something* to do with Torah.) And [its use](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah) is very broad. Currently, the tag is useless. What should we do?

Comment: Later: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2114

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest we remove the `torah` tag wherever it's used, and create a few tags with `torah` in their name (which can be chosen to correspond to [current uses of the `torah` tag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah), such as `torah-scroll`, `torah-shebichtav`, and `kabalat-hatorah`) so they come up as tag suggestions, and convert future uses of plain `torah`.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Here are some existing "torah" tags: oral-torah, parshanut-torah-comment, parsha-torah-portion, sefer-torah, torah-learning, torah-reading, torah-service

Comment: I've now removed the `torah` tag from all questions AFAICT, replacing with something finer where suitable.